# Abbott Understanding Analysis 2nd ed Exercise 2.7.2

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to decide whether the series converge or diverge and am struggling with two different series.  I am able to use the comparison test, the absolute convergence test, the alternating series test, and the ratio test.

The first series is:

$$1 + \frac12 - \frac13 + \frac14 + \frac15 - \frac16+\cdots$$
(I believe this diverges) I was trying to use the comparison test using the harmonic series since it diverges, but I don't think the harmonic series is less than this series, in which case, I can't show that it diverges.

The second series is:  $$1 - \frac1{2^2} + \frac13 - \frac1{4^2} + \frac15 - \frac1{6^2}+\cdots$$  (I believe this one also diverges)  I was trying to split this into two different series $(\frac1{2n-1})$ and $(\frac1{(2n)^2})$.  For the second series, I can use the comparison test.  Since it is less than the series $\frac1{n^2}$, I can say that it converges.  I was trying to use the comparison test with the first one as well, but am struggling to find another series to compare it to.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Just to be certain, what is the pattern of the signs of the first series? Is it +,+,-, repeating with period 3?

Comment: Correct.  +, +, -, +, +, -, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Both series are divergent. For the series $ 1 + \tfrac{1}{2} - \tfrac{1}{3} + \tfrac{1}{4} + \tfrac{1}{5} - \tfrac{1}{6} + \tfrac{1}{7} + \tfrac{1}{8} - \tfrac{1}{9} + \cdots $, let $ (s_n) $ be the sequence of partial sums and consider the subsequence $ (s_{3n}) $:
\begin{align*}
    s_{3n} = \,\, & \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{3} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{6} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac{1}{3n - 2} + \frac{1}{3n - 1} - \frac{1}{3n} \right) \\[2mm]
    \geq \,\, & \left( 1 + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{5} - \frac{1}{5} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac{1}{3n - 2} + \frac{1}{3n - 1} - \frac{1}{3n - 1} \right) \\[2mm]
    = \,\, & 1 + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{3n - 2} \\[2mm]
    = \,\, & \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{3k - 2} \\[2mm]
    = \,\, & \frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k - \tfrac{2}{3}} \\[2mm]
    \geq \,\, & \frac{1}{3} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}.
\end{align*}
This demonstrates that $ s_{3n} \geq \tfrac{1}{3} \sum_{k=1}^n \tfrac{1}{k} $ for all positive integers $ n $. Since $ \sum_{k=1}^n \tfrac{1}{k} $ is unbounded in $ n $ (this is the partial sum for the harmonic series, Example 2.4.5 of Abbott 2nd edition), it follows that
$$
    (s_{3n}) \text{ is unbounded} \implies (s_n) \text{ is unbounded} \implies (s_n) \text{ is divergent}.
$$

For the series $ 1 - \tfrac{1}{2^2} + \tfrac{1}{3} - \tfrac{1}{4^2} + \tfrac{1}{5} - \tfrac{1}{6^2} + \tfrac{1}{7} - \tfrac{1}{8^2} + \cdots $, let $ (s_n) $ be the sequence of partial sums. Let's look at the subsequence $ (s_{2n}) $. For any $ m \geq 2 $, we have
$$
    \frac{1}{m^2} \leq \frac{1}{m(m-1)} = \frac{1}{m-1} - \frac{1}{m} \implies -\frac{1}{m^2} \geq - \frac{1}{m-1} + \frac{1}{m}.
$$
Applying this to the subsequence:
\begin{align*}
    s_{2n} = \,\, & \left( 1 - \frac{1}{2^2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{4^2} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac{1}{2n - 1} - \frac{1}{(2n)^2} \right) \\[2mm]
    \geq \,\, & \left( 1 - 1 + \frac{1}{2} \right) + \left( \frac{1}{3} - \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} \right) + \cdots + \left( \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n-1} + \frac{1}{2n} \right) \\[2mm]
    = \,\, & \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2n} \\[2mm]
    = \,\, & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k}.
\end{align*}
We may conclude that
$$
    (s_{2n}) \text{ is unbounded} \implies (s_n) \text{ is unbounded} \implies (s_n) \text{ is divergent}.
$$